# Problems with menu fixed top on scroll, when html document not enough height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I do a menu fixed top when scroll, it ok with some pages have large height, but in page has not enough height, this script loop:

**Example:**

I have menu with height 50px and i write a script:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50){
    // add class fixed
} else { //remove class }
```

- on pages with large height this run: `scroll(over 50px) > add class`
- on pages with small height this run: `scroll(over 50px) > add class > remove class`

Please see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/F4BmP/2930/

Comment: @Nguyen huy so u mean you not only what to add a class depending on a scroll position , but also add or remove a class on window / screen size ?

Comment: yes, i mean that have a problems with window/screen size, you can try examble, when you scroll at the end, it will auto jump to the top, so it make a loop add and remove class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, i find a solution for my problem.

Reason make problem is HTML document lost height when menu change from static to fixed.Examble: Browser has 500px and has a scrollbar, when user scroll my menu change to fixed and browser lost 50px of menu, so browser not enough height to has scrollbar, it will return to top page and do code lines in ELSE statement.

So i add a div wrap my menu and set height the same height with my menu, this will make the height of document always the same on before and after scroll:

```
<div id="wrap" style="height:50px;width:100%">
      <div id="mymenu"></div>
</div>
```

This solution solve my problem.

Comment: Great solution. Just little improvement : the height of menu can change (dynamic content or responsive website) so I set height of the wrap div in JS just before the class `fixedNav` is added and i removed it when the class is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var elementPosition = $('.menu').offset();

$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
              $('.menu').css('position','fixed').css('top','0');
              $('.menu').css('width','100%');
              $('.menu').css('z-index','500');
        } else {
            $('.menu').css('position','static');
        }    
});
});
```

Well, this code is working on my menubar, even if screen size is different .

Comment: So, this code not working for my situation, when the browser not enough height, when you scroll at the end, it will auto jump to the top.You can try my examble, can't reach at the end of scrollbar

Comment: ohh i see, when i see your example, there's nothing wrong from your example, but when i delete the <br> into 4 <br> the (Bottom!) didn't appear, is that what you mean??

Comment: Yes, i mean that .I know the reason make problem, because when set the menu fixed, document lost height the same height of menu, so scrollbar of browser  disappear and scrollTop decrease and jump to Else statement but i don't know how to resolve it

Comment: Hmmm sorry, i got confused by your question. My english is bad, anyway. :)

Well, if your problem is the (Bottom!) didn't appear, it was because you set the menu class position to absolute, it will make the (Bottom!) covered by your menu when height isn't enough(your 'bottom!' is behind the menu), and scrollbar won't appear too, to make your (bottom!) still appear even when height isn't enough, you need to set your (Bottom!) position:fixed and bottom:0.

Answer (score 0):

Basic concept is user has to see the menu while scrolling the page.

But in your functionality is correct.There is no much content and User can see the menu in current screen itself. If there is more content user can scroll and get sticky menu always on top.

If you really want to make browser scroll you can give `min-height`for container.

Example

```
.containerclassname{
  min-height: 1500px;
}
```

Comment: this not solve my problem, because it will make a blank on my web page

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in firefox and also in chrome , the issue seems to be in chrome . i reworked the code both html and JS and it works fine in chrome, for for that matter in any browser .

heres what should probably work for you :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
             $(window).scroll(function (e) {
                    $el = $('.nav');
                    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                        $('.nav').addClass("fixedNav");
                    }else {
                        $('.nav').removeClass("fixedNav");
                    }
                });
             });
```

the entire code is enclosed in a fiddle .

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2q7zk0m/)

Kind regards .

Alexander .

Comment: I will try your code on next monday and reply you soon

Comment: this code not working to me, because it still not solve the problem when menu add class fixed, sometime the screen not enough height when resize or screen resolution, and when menu is fixed, document lost height of menu and make browser lost scrollbar, that will run else statement immediately

Comment: @NguyễnHuy , matbe this may help : http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jumpy-navigation-code-in-chrome

Comment: I had found out a solution for my problem, it working nice on IE 8+, chrome and firefox, i had updated answer above, but anyway, thanks you so much.